# Java 8 Sorting Custom Sorting

Tags: sorting, java-8

```
    class A {
        private String name;
        private int grade;
        private RD rd;
    
        // setters & getters
    }
    class RD {
        private double ef;
        private double mf;
        private int doe;
    
        // setters & getters
    }
```

Custom Sorting based on 4 different columns.

1. Grade, in ascending order
2. ef in descending order
3. doe in ascending order
4. mf in descending order
   I tried it doing it.

But i am not getting the proper output.

Here is what i did.

```
    class SortingCustom {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
            Collections.sort(aList, Comparator.comparing(A::getGrade)
                    .thenComparing((A a, A b) -> {
                           return Double.compare(b.getRd().getEf(), a.getRd().getEf());
                    })
                    .thenComparing((A a, A b) -> {
                           return Integer.compare(a.getRd().getDoe(), b.getRd().getDoe());
                    })
                    .thenComparing((A a, A b) -> {
                           return Double.compare(b.getRd().getMf(), a.getRd().getMf());
                    })
            );
            //This doesnot sort all data.
        } 
    }
```

## Sample Output

```
Grade   EF      DOE    MF
======  =====  =====   ====
1       0.27     4     0.72
2       0.98     2     0.34
2       0.96     3     0.93
2       0.96     3     0.91
2       0.96     3     0.87
2       0.96     3     0.65
2       0.96     4     0.34
2       0.87     4     0.25
3       0.67     4     0.22
3       0.45     6     0.17
```

Comment: I have added the sample Response.

Comment: `Double.compare` will return 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2, hope you  align with that

Comment: @User well, that's precisely what a comparator is supposed to do.

Comment: @Bishwajit The order of your sort criteria does not match the order in your comparator chain. Further, there's not even an attempt to use descending order.

Comment: You can do it simpler, `aList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(A::getGrade) .thenComparingDouble(a -> -a.getRd().getEf()) .thenComparingInt(a -> a.getRd().getDoe()) .thenComparingDouble(a -> -a.getRd().getMf()));` Note that while using minus to reverse the order works for floating point types, you should not use it for integer types.

Comment: @Holger Even after using the logic you send it did not work.
I've edited the comparator chain logic to match the  requirement. Sorry for that.

Comment: Then, provide a complete example and the output you got instead of the intended one.

Comment: Adding the data in random order and then sorting it gives me the exact same order as your output. Do you add all your data before sorting?